# Square Number Patterns

Tags: c#

Good day, I am having difficulties in this program
My Code is

```
using System;
class Pattern{
static void Main()
{
int rows, i, j, k;


Console.WriteLine("Enter the no. of rows: ");
rows = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
{
 

  for (j = 1; j <= rows; j++)
  {
      k=i+j-1;
      if (k>rows){
      k=k-2;
      }
      Console.Write(k+ " ");
    
    
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
}
}
```

The output that I get is

```
123
232
323
```

The output that I want to get is
When I input 3
the output should be

```
123
232
321
```

When I input 4
the output should be

```
1234
2343
3432
4321
```

What seems to be wrong in my code? Thank you

Comment: The square should be surrounded by `123` in any direction?

Comment: no just a loop of numbers like a square pattern using asterix

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System; class Pattern{
    static void Main()
    {
        int rows, i;
        string x = "1";
        
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the no. of rows: ");
        rows = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
        for(i = 2; i<= rows; i++){
            x = x+ i.ToString();
        }
        for(i = rows-1; i>= 1; i--){
            x = x+ i.ToString();
        }
        
        for(i = 0; i< rows; i++){
            Console.WriteLine(x.Substring(i, rows));
        }
        
    } }
```

You may try this solution but it's different with using looping for iteration. You may try your own solution, i hope my solution is correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
    int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        string s = string.Empty;
        for (int j = i; j <= count + i - 1; j++)
        {
            int v;
            if (j > count)
            {
                v = count - (j - count);
            }
            else
            {
                v = j;
            }
            s += v;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```